# Using Manipulate to find best starting parameters to fit data

Tags: manipulate, fitting

Often, curve fitting is very sensitive to starting values of parameters. It would be great, if I could to find such starting values of parameters "by hand" using Manipulate.

So, I plot in Manipulate my experimental data points and theoretical curve. I can change the shape of this curve by changing all parameters in manipulate in such way that they approximate my experimental data relatively well. Now I would like to run fitting using current parameters in Manipulate as starting values. Finally I would like to insert the parameters found by fitting back into Manipulate.

Here is example code for simple function. My data is more complex.

```
data = Table[{x, 8 x^3 - 7 x^2 - 10 x + 1 + RandomReal[{-5, 5}]}, {x, -2, 2, 0.1}];
Manipulate[
 Show[
  Plot[a x^3 + b x^2 + c x + d, {x, -2, 2}],
  ListPlot[data]
 ],
 {a, -10, 10},
 {b, -10, 10},
 {c, -10, 10},
 {d, -10, 10}
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I understand the question a curve fitting procedure that has the following properties is sought:

1. Manually adjust the parameters to get an approximate fit.
2. Use these parameters as the starting values for `FindFit`.
3. Propagate the solution from `FindFit` back to the `Manipulate` parameters.
4. Subsequently enable further editing of the `Manipulate` parameters and repeat the cycle.

The following code satisfies this criteria by wrapping `Manipulate` inside a `DynamicModule` and the use of a `Button` to indicate when `FindFit` should be run.

```
data = Table[{x, 8 x^3 - 7 x^2 - 10 x + 1 + RandomReal[{-5, 5}]}, {x, -2, 2, 0.1}];

DynamicModule[
 {
  sol
  },

 Manipulate[

  If[computeFlag == True,
   sol = FindFit[data, 
     aa x^3 + bb x^2 + cc x + 
      dd, {{aa, a}, {bb, b}, {cc, c}, {dd, d}}, x];
   {a, b, c, d} = {aa, bb, cc, dd} /. sol;
   computeFlag = False;
   ];

  Column[{
    Dynamic[
     Button["Compute",
      computeFlag = True
      ]
     ],
    Show[
     Plot[a x^3 + b x^2 + c x + d, {x, -2, 2},
      PlotStyle -> Black],
     ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red],
     ImageSize -> 300,
     PlotRange -> {{-2.05, 2.05}, All}
     ]
    }],

  (*Manipulate variables*)
  {{computeFlag, False}, ControlType -> None},

  {{a, 1}, -10, 10, Appearance -> "Open"},
  {{b, 1}, -10, 10, Appearance -> "Open"},
  {{c, 1}, -10, 10, Appearance -> "Open"},
  {{d, 1}, -10, 10, Appearance -> "Open"}

  ] (* end of Manipulate *)
 ] (* end of DynamicModule *)
```

Below is a figure where the parameters have been manually adjusted.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

After clicking the Compute button `FindFit` propagates the solution back to the `Manipulate` parameters.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The user is free to re-edit the `Manipulate` parameters and repeat the cycle.

Answer (score 2):

```
dynamicFit[data_, expr_, pars_] :=
 With[{
   n = Length[pars],
   x1 = Min[First /@ data],
   x2 = Max[First /@ data]},
  DynamicModule[{pars2, fit, fitted = Null},
   pars2 = Table[Unique[], n];
   Do[pars2[[i]] = RandomReal[{-2, 2}], {i, n}];
   Column[{
     Sequence @@ Table[
       With[{i = i},
        Labeled[
         Slider[Dynamic[pars2[[i]]], {-10, 10}, 
          Appearance -> "Labeled",
          ImageSize -> 275], pars[[i]], Left]], {i, n}],
     Dynamic@Framed@Show[
        Plot[Evaluate[{expr[x] /. Thread[pars -> pars2], fitted}],
         {x, x1, x2}],
        ListPlot[data],
        ImageSize -> 300],
     Row[{
       Button["Fit",
        fit = FindFit[data, expr[x], Transpose[{pars, pars2}], x];
        fitted = expr[x] /. fit,
        ImageSize -> Automatic],
       Button["Export",
        exported = fitted,
        ImageSize -> Automatic]
       }]
     }]
   ]
  ]
```

Parameters are: `data`, model `expr` (as a Function) and model parameters `pars` (used in the model). Your arguments can be quite general as long as the data is 2D and model a function of one variable. Clear `exported` before invoking the routine, adjust parameters dynamically, try a fit, adjust some more ... eventually export the fit to `exported`.

```
test = Table[{x,
    x + Sin[3 x] + RandomReal[{-.5, .5}]}, {x, -3, 3, 0.1}];

exported = Null;
dynamicFit[test, Function[x, a x + Sin[b x]], {a, b}]
```

[image]

The fit resides in `exported`. This is a bit clumsy, I wish I knew how to do it better.

```
exported
```

> 0.995803 x + Sin[3.04859 x]

Comment: This is a very fine piece of work. One small error was the argument of `ListPlot` was `test` and should have been `data`. You could add `fit` or `fitted` or the  to the row with the buttons to show the values of the fitted parameters.

Comment: @JackLaVigne Thanks, `test` was a residue. Many features can be readily added if one wants. Also, the question asked for `Manipulate`, but I didn't use it because I find it generates a very complex dynamic structures which I don't understand as well as a custom dynamic object.

Answer (score 1):

Initalize:

```
data = Table[{x, 
    8 x^3 - 7 x^2 - 10 x + 1 + RandomReal[{-5, 5}]}, {x, -2, 2, 
    0.1}];
l = {a -> 1, b -> 1, c -> 1, d -> 1}
```

Now run the following code, you can change the settings and then re-evaluate and it will start with the new parameters.

```
aa = a /. l;
bb = b /. l;
cc = c /. l;
dd = d /. l;
l = FindFit[data, 
  a x^3 + b x^2 + c x + d, {{a, aa}, {b, bb}, {c, cc}, {d, dd}}, x]
Manipulate[aa = a; bb = b; cc = c; dd = d; 
 Show[Plot[a x^3 + b x^2 + c x + d, {x, -2, 2}], 
  ListPlot[data]], {{a, aa}, -10, 10}, {{b, bb}, -10, 
  10}, {{c, cc}, -10, 10}, {{d, dd}, -10, 10}]
```

Answer (score 0):

After manipulation you will have `value = {a,b,c,d}`.  Replotting is probably best done with a separate evaluation.

```
data = Table[{x, 8 x^3 - 7 x^2 - 10 x + 1 + RandomReal[{-5, 5}]}, {x, -2, 2, 0.1}];
Manipulate[
 values = {a,b,c,d};
 Show[
  Plot[a x^3 + b x^2 + c x + d, {x, -2, 2}],
  ListPlot[data]
 ],
 {a, -10, 10},
 {b, -10, 10},
 {c, -10, 10},
 {d, -10, 10}
]
```

Comment: I'm not sure I will be satisfied with fit. So I will move the parameters again by hands and thus go back to  Manipulate, than again to Fit and so on.. That is why I would like to fit inside the Manipulate

Comment: `FindFit[]` within a dynamic function is a bad idea.