# Apply ToString to a list of variables

Tags: list-manipulation, evaluation, assignment, variable

I have

```
data1 = {1, 1};
data2 = {2, 2};
datalist = {data1, data2};
```

I want to create a string list based on the variable names inside `datalist`, in this case:

```
{"data1", "data2"};
```

`ToString` function does not work as it makes all possible evaluations first:

```
ToString[datalist]

(* {{1, 1}, {2, 2}} *)
```

Also tried:

```
ToString /@ HoldForm /@ Unevaluated @ datalist

(* {{1, 1}, {2, 2}} *)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: maybe something like `listnames = Flatten[StringCases[
   ToString /@ {OwnValues@data1, OwnValues@data2}[[All, 1, 1]], 
   "HoldPattern[" ~~ x__ ~~ "]" :> x]]`?

Comment: Depending on what other variable names exist something based on `Names["data@"]` gives you a list of strings:  `{"data1", "data2", "datalist"}`.

Comment: Variable names that hold data in the name is usually a bad idea, imho.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In addition to [Mr.Wizard's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/139909/280) here is a collection of other possibilities:

```
data1 = {1, 1};
data2 = {2, 2};
datalist := {data1, data2};

ToString /@ Map[HoldForm, OwnValues[datalist], {3}][[1, 2]]
ToString /@ Map[Unevaluated, OwnValues[datalist], {3}][[1, 2]]
ToString /@ Thread[HoldForm[datalist] /. OwnValues[datalist]]
ToString /@ Thread[Extract[OwnValues[datalist], {1, 2}, HoldForm]]
ToString /@ Thread[Extract[OwnValues[datalist], {1, 2}, Unevaluated]]
ToString /@ Thread[Rest@Level[OwnValues[datalist], {2}, HoldForm]]
ToString /@ Thread[Rest@Level[OwnValues[datalist], {2}, Unevaluated]]
Unevaluated[Block[datalist, ToString /@ datalist]] /. OwnValues[datalist]
Cases[OwnValues[datalist], s_ :> Block[{s}, ToString@s], {3}] // Rest
Cases[OwnValues[datalist], s : {___} :> Block[s, ToString /@ s], {2}][[1]]
FirstCase[OwnValues[datalist], s : {__} :> Block[s, ToString /@ s], {}, {2}]
Cases[OwnValues[datalist], s : {___} :> ToString /@ Thread[HoldForm@s], {2}][[1]]
FirstCase[OwnValues[datalist], s : {__} :> ToString /@ Thread[HoldForm@s], {}, {2}]
```

> ```
> {"data1", "data2"}
>
> {"data1", "data2"}
>
> {"data1", "data2"}
>
> {"data1", "data2"}
>
> {"data1", "data2"}
>
> {"data1", "data2"}
>
> {"data1", "data2"}
>
> {"data1", "data2"}
>
> {"data1", "data2"}
>
> {"data1", "data2"}
>
> {"data1", "data2"}
>
> {"data1", "data2"}
>
> {"data1", "data2"}
> ```

All the above methods work correctly when `datalist` is empty:

```
datalist := {};
ToString /@ Map[HoldForm, OwnValues[datalist], {-1}][[1, 2]]
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

Comment: Not quite sure the use of `OwnValues` here, Could you explain a bit or give a ref? the Mathematica page does not help...@Alexey

Comment: @Leo1215 Here are some references in recommended order of reading: [1](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18456/280), [2](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions.html), [3](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96/280).

Answer (score 6):

You're going to first need to hold `{data1,data2}` unevaluated in some way; either define it *first*, use [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) (short form `:=`), or use [`Hold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hold.html).  I choose `:=`.

```
data1 = {1, 1};
data2 = {2, 2};
datalist := {data1, data2};

Cases[OwnValues[datalist], x_ :> ToString@Unevaluated@x, {3}] // Rest
```

> ```
> {"data1", "data2"}
> ```

Or using [my `step` function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/334/121):

```
Cases[step[datalist], x_ :> ToString@Unevaluated@x, {2}]
```

> ```
> {"data1", "data2"}
> ```

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55764/5478 :)

Comment: @Kuba Yes, I am senile. Thanks for finding the duplicate and marking it.